# How to maximize Headless Chrome window in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, google-chrome-headless

I'm not able to start Headless chrome with a maximized window. I tried two solutions but none of them worked for me. 
First solution :

```
Open Browser    ${LOGIN_URL}    headlesschrome
Maximize Browser Window
```

Second one :

```
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
Go To   ${LOGIN_URL}
Maximize Browser Window
```

what's the thing i'm doing wrong in my solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use Set Window Size :

```
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
Set Window Size ${1400} ${600}
Go To   ${LOGIN_URL}
```

Answer (score 1):

To maximize the *Browsing Window* while using [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) you need to replace:

```
add_argument    --start-maximized
```

With:

```
add_argument    window-size=1400,600
```

---

### Alternative

The command `Maximize Browser Window` may still not be working in [robotframework](/questions/tagged/robotframework).

This is a known issue with *robotframework* for quite some time now. We have discussed this issue within the discussion ["Maximise browser Window" keyword not working in IE,FF and chrome.I am using selenium2Library](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/123) at length. However there is a work around provided by `@srib4ufrnd` as follows:

- Step 1: When selenium2library is installed in robot frame work , the selenium2library will create the python files (these python files contains the python code for selenium keywords) in the path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords`
- Step 2: Among these python files the code for keyword **`Maximise browser window`** is present in the python file with name `browsermanagement.py`
- Step3: The code for **Maximise browser window** is not working.

  ```
  def maximize_browser_window(self):
      """Maximizes current browser window."""
      self._current_browser().execute_script("if (window.screen) { window.moveTo(0, 0); window.resizeTo(window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight); }")
  ```
- Step 4: Copy the above file and save it with another name for backup sake. This will help us if we need to revert back quickly incase of any issues.
- Step 5: Now replace the above mentioned code in the "_browsermanagement.py" file with the following code.

  ```
  def maximize_browser_window(self):
      """Maximizes current browser window."""
      self._current_browser().maximize_window()
  ```
- Step 6: Save the file `_browsermanagement.py` after editing.

> Note: Ensure you are saving the file in proper encoding technique using only "notepad" which comes as deafult with windows to edit and save the file.

- Step 7: Execute your test which can now perform the same operation of the keyword **Maximise browser window**.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)
- [Not able to maximize Chrome Window in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374377/not-able-to-maximize-chrome-window-in-headless-mode/45374670#45374670)

Comment: i got this error : Calling method 'add_argument' failed: TypeError: add_argument() got an unexpected keyword argument '--window-size'

Comment: @AbdoRabah Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks i've found this solution using `Set Window Size ${1400} ${600}`

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me

```
Call Method    ${chrome options}     add_argument    window-size\=1400,600
```

notice the `\=` because without it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me.

```
${options}    Evaluate    {"args": ["headless=True", "window-size=1920,1080"]}
${chrome_options}    Evaluate    selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()    selenium.webdriver

Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    ${options["args"][0]}
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    ${options["args"][1]}

Open browser    ${URL}      Chrome     executable_path=Chromedriverpath     options=${chrome_options}
```