# Selenium in Java is not finding element when using headless Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I want to find some elements from an JavaScript based website. I use Java and Selenium. Everything works fine, but when I want to use headless Chrome, then Selenium is not able to find the elements.

I added this options to my ChromeDriver:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

Console:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2020-08-27 22:41:46.625  INFO 20344 --- [ null to remote] o.o.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake    : Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "Thread-8" Exception in thread "Thread-10" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.cssSelector: [data-id='current-price'] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at magharmi.asos.pricechecker.controller.PriceController$1.run(PriceController.java:52)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-id='current-price']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.83)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-MMDJR4G', ip: '192.168.178.45', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Comment: Apparently chrome not making objects. Add some more debug,n pike is anything found...simple top levrl elements? If chrome not creating, selenium cant find the. Try firefix to see or a lower version of chrome?

Comment: Yes, top level elements. I just want to find a price from a product site of a shop. The price is loaded a bit later, so it is not shown immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) mode you need to:

- [Maximize the browsing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374377/not-able-to-maximize-chrome-window-in-headless-mode/45374670#45374670)

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--window-size=1400,600");
  ```
- Instead of `presenceOfElementLocated()` induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for `visibilityOfElementLocated()` as follows:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[data-id='current-price']")));
  ```