# How can I execute a "scrollIntoView()" function if the headless of the webdriver is equals to True?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to execute a code that scrolls down an inner div to a certain element. That just works if:

```
Options().headless = False
```

But as you guys know, that isn't good to the performance of the whole thing.

The code that do the scroll is:

```
element = driver1.find_element_by_xpath(reference)
driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

How can I do something like that, but with the headless equals to True?

Comment: It should be exactly same. Did you try and face any issue ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run the code with both situations, and when the headless is equal to True, an error occurs.

Comment: What is error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354364/scrollintoview-method-implementation/59356940#59356940) must work identically irrespective of `Options().headless = True` or `Options().headless = False`.

However, while using [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) mode you need to:

- [Maximize the browsing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python/55016352#55016352)

  ```
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
  ```
- Additionally induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "reference")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium in Java is not finding element when using headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623917/selenium-in-java-is-not-finding-element-when-using-headless-chrome/63628975#63628975)