# Fullscreen in Headless Chrome using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless

I have a number of tests in an E2E suite where a video element is fullscreened and the fullscreen status is verified. However, when running the suite headlessly, these tests fail. Screenshots of the page show the video is simply not in fullscreen, even after the fullscreen button is clicked. Is there a way to achieve fullscreen functionality in headless Chrome?

Here is an example of the capabilities in my config.

```
capabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['headless']
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to set window-size to fullscreen for headless-chrome using chrome options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796194/how-to-set-window-size-to-fullscreen-for-headless-chrome-using-chrome-options) You can't run headless if you want full-screen capability.

Answer (score 0):

When the argument `--start-fullscreen` is added to initialize [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in normal mode it seems the screen size is:

```
1366 x 724px
```

Snapshot:

[image: visible--start-fullscreen]

---

Whilst [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) when initiated additionally with either of the arguments:

- `--start-maximized`
- `--kiosk`
- `--start-fullscreen`

The resultant screen size is always:

```
800 x 600px
```

Snapshot:

[image: using--start-fullscreen]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that in *`--headless`* mode Chrome browser always opens in *`800` x `600`px* size ignoring the customized `--window-size` arguments.

Comment: I was not referring to the `--window-size` argument, but rather entering fullscreen during the test run, by clicking a fullscreen button on a video. Though my question wasn't answered directly, this makes me think it is not possible to achieve this.